# preg_replace replace where IP

Tags: php, regex

i am a total beginner to regex and such and i have no idea whatsoever on how to construct a filter for it. What i'm basically wanting to do is:

I have a .txt file, with IP's and unix timestamps, for example `11.11.11.11:1393598` (IP:timestamp) and what i want to do with regex is replace the timestamp that is associated with a certain IP, so if there are 3 ip's and timestamps in the textfile (seperated by spaces) i want to replace only the one with ip `11.11.11.11 (11.11.11.11:343434 to 11.11.11.11:999999)`, now i am totally new to the whole regex thing so i really have no clue what to do, so i have no code that i have tried :/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're new to regular expressions and haven't yet been able to try any code, then Stack Overflow is not the correct venue for your question, as this is too broad a topic. You should do some reading and learning first, then try some code, and then if you can't get it, post a question on Stack Overflow with your specific problem.

Comment: i have been looking at tutorials and such for about 2 hours now, and it still looks like ancient egyptian for me. I was hoping that some nice soul would be able to help me with this single question, because i don't really want to read 3 books and go to school for a year only to solve this small question that would probably take 20 seconds for somebody that has already gone through the hassle of learning everything to solve.

Comment: and to narrow down my question i want to replace every instance of "11.11.11.11:999999" to "11.11.11.11:222222"

Comment: @SimonAndersson well then, isn't a simple search and replace enough ?

Comment: The site http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has been linked quite a bit on this site. You might try there. But if all you want to do is replace that actual literal string with the other actual literal string, regular expressions wouldn't be needed.

Comment: The thing is i only know the IP, and the second number is undetermined, so i need to replace 11.11.11.11:(anything) to something else, and i figured i need to use regex for that

Comment: @SimonAndersson Promise me that you will [learn regex one day](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/). `(192\.168\.1\.1):\d+` and replace with `$1:yournumber`.

Comment: @HamZa i promise one day i will try to learn this alien language.

Comment: A good exercise might be to reverse engineer the answer and see why it works. @HamZa That is an awesome website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '11.11.11.11:1393598';
$search = preg_quote('11.11.11.11');
$replace = '999999';
$string = preg_replace("/($search):\d+/", "$1:$replace", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, and I don't know php very well.

```
 # $str = preg_replace_callback('/(11(?:\.11){3}:)(?:(343434)|(999999))/',
 #              function( $matches ){
 #                   $repl = "999999";
 #                   if ( $matches[3] != "" ) {
 #                        $repl = "222222";
 #                   }
 #                   return $matches[1] . $repl;
 #              },
 #              $str);
 # 
 # 

 # (11(?:\.11){3}:)(?:(343434)|(999999))

 (                                  # (1 start)
      11
      (?: \.11 ){3}
      :
 )                                  # (1 end)
 (?:
      ( 343434 )                    # (2)
   |  ( 999999 )                    # (3)
 )
```